# Remove error logging in production using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a React/Next.js website which I created using create-next-app so it handles all of the webpack stuff for me. I know very little about webpack or how to configure it so my question might seem incredibly simple to some.

I have my own logging service which I call using log.info() instead of console.log().

I'd like to remove every line which contains "log.info(" and anything after it (and whitespace before it). It should do this only when doing a next build (for production), not when you do npm run dev.

I'm hoping I can achieve this with some kind of webpack plugin or script and I'm hoping I can run it before Next/Webpack does it's thing and minifies everything onto one line.

I'd appreciate any shove int he right direction as googling has drawn a blank.

Comment: tried plain old replacer yet? https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader

Comment: Not yet, but i'll give it a go. It looks like it might be exactly what I need. I'm terrible with regexes but I'm sure I can work it out. Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't already knew https://regex101.com/ is a fantastic trial and error site

Comment: or you can write your own babel plugin/webpack plugin and use it.